# ruby on Rails:--How can I ignore/remove dst from Datetime civil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method `DateTime.civil(...)` want to ignore `dst` on this

I can check the dst using `dst?` `isdst` but how can I ignore dst?

Any kind of help will be really helpful for me.

I got some links like [Rails ignore daylight savings time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602213/rails-ignore-daylight-savings-time) also many other but they are even not much helpful

but they are not ignore dst from `Datetime.civil` functionality

**we can skip it in model using `skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes` same thing can we do for view I do not want to show it as string**

thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you ignore DST? Don't you just mean you want to print a date without DST information? Or do you want UTC time?

Comment: There is a similar question here

[Make Rails ignore daylight saving time][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541571/make-rails-ignore-daylight-saving-time-when-displaying-a-date

Comment: no....  @Bala i have also find that..but thanks

Comment: @zwippie I want the print date without dst

Comment: @badal Then take a look at the [Time#strftime docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime)

Comment: @zwippie you did not get my point  actually we can skip it in model using `skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes` same thing can we do for view I do not want to show it as string

Comment: If you are not going to print the date, what will you do with it? On the topic of timezones and DST: if the [link from Bala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541571/make-rails-ignore-daylight-saving-time-when-displaying-a-date) did not help, perhaps [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices) will.